# Why do `map(foo)` and `map{ foo($0) }` return different results?

Tags: swift

For the following code snippet, why do `res1` and `res2` have different values?

```swift
func test() {
    let a: String? = nil
    let b: String? = nil

    let foo: (String?) -> Int = { $0 == nil ? 0 : 1}

    let res1 = [a, b].compactMap { $0 }.map(foo)
    let res2 = [a, b].compactMap { $0 }.map { foo($0) }

    print("res1: ", res1)
    print("res2: ", res2)
}
```

The output is

```
res1:  [0, 0]
res2:  []
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. IMO both should result in an empty collection.

Comment: Interestingly, `compacted()` yields the correct result for each. Always use `compacted` nowadays. The people who maintain the Algorithms package care the most.

Comment: @Jessy The reason `compacted()` behaves differently is that the types are entirely different — because `compacted()` returns a new `CompactedSequence` `struct`, the compiler can't implicitly upcast it like it can `Array` (which has special variance treatment in the compiler), so the type checker has a very straightforward time selecting types that fit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a result in how the compiler selects the types of `[a, b].compactMap` based on the downstream operation. You can see this by inspecting the types of the arguments as they pass through the functions:

```swift
func printType<T>(_ i: String, _ v: T) -> T {
  print(i, "->", T.self)
  return v
}

func test() {
    let a: String? = nil
    let b: String? = nil

    let foo: (String?) -> Int = { $0 == nil ? 0 : 1 }

    let res1 = printType("cm1", printType("a1", [a, b]).compactMap { $0 }).map(foo)
    let res2 = printType("cm2", printType("a2", [a, b]).compactMap { $0 }).map { foo($0) }

    print("res1: ", res1)
    print("res2: ", res2)
}

test()
// a1 -> Array<Optional<Optional<String>>>
// cm1 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// a2 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// cm2 -> Array<String>
// res1:  [0, 0]
// res2:  []
```

It appears that:

1. In the case of `res1`:

   - Because `foo` takes a `String`, `map(foo)` is typed such that a `String?` is passed through — and for `map` to be receiving a `String?`, `compactMap` must be returning a `[String?]`
   - In order for `compactMap` to be returning a `[String?]`, its input must be a `[String??]`
   - Although `[a, b]` defaults to being a `[String?]`, the compiler can also implicitly *upcast* it to a `[String??]`, so that's what it does
   - Hence, only one layer of optionality is removed from `[String??]`, and each of the `String?` values is passed to the `map` and into `foo`
2. In the case of `res2`, the compiler isn't restricted as heavily by `map { foo($0) }`, since `$0` can be implicitly upcast *inside* of the closure before being passed to `foo`, and this is what the compiler prefers:

   - `$0` is a `String` which is *upcast* to `String?` before being passed to `foo`
   - For `map` to receive `String` values, `compactMap` must return `[String]`
   - Since `compactMap` is returning a `[String]`, its input must be `[String?]`, which `[a, b]` is, no upcasting needed
   - Hence, now `compactMap` is actually filtering the `nil`s out of `[String?]` into `[String]`, and since no values are left, `foo` is never even called (you can see this with more print statements inside of `foo`

This sort of thing is *very* situational in the compiler, and you happened to have found a specific case where this happens. For instance, the compiler parses the results of single-statement closures differently from multi-statement closures: if you turn `compactMap { $0 }` into `compactMap { _ = 1 + 1; return $0 }`, the closure will parsed differently, and type checking will occur in a different order, resulting in `[]` in both cases:

```swift
let res1 = printType("cm1", printType("a1", [a, b]).compactMap { _ = 1 + 1; return $0 }).map(foo)
let res2 = printType("cm2", printType("a2", [a, b]).compactMap { _ = 1 + 1; return $0 }).map { foo($0) }

// a1 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// cm1 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// a2 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// cm2 -> Array<Optional<String>>
// res1:  [0, 0]
// res2:  [0, 0]
```

In this case, the compiler actually ended up preferring the *surprising* case in both instances, since `return $0` allows the compiler to upcast from `String?` ➡ `String??` (and then filter back down from `[String??]` ➡ `[String?]`)!

Either way, this seems worthy of a report on https://bugs.swift.org, since the behavior is incredibly surprising. I will be happy to add test cases and comments to the report if you go ahead and file.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I filed a report (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-16075).

Comment: @BoxuanZhang Excellent! I hope you don't mind, but I added some more details inline in the issue.